# VS2015 cant find reference file, while its there

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am having a problem with vs2015
I've been working for a month on a project.
And as of today suddenly i get "System.IO.FileNotFoundException" error when running my app from visual studio, and also the app wont run without visual studio, while visual studio can still compile the file.

I removed and recreated all external .dll references.
But so far no luck, i can browse to those files they do exist.
One of the files is the Microsoft.Kinect.dll  and i didnt write that file.
The file is unchanged, and i got no clue as of why visual studio cannt open the file.

I also went back to previously working versions of my application same problem. None of the external references seams to work any-more.

I run windows 10 version 10586.63

How can i debug this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem had started after an update to windows build 10586.63
After i roled back that major build release, everything worked again (including office 365).

This wasn't a visual studio bug, it was a windows NT core bug.
When i posted it here i didnt knew that the whole system had been updated.
I tought by the text Microsoft presented with this update, that it was only about adding new features (as i got cortana)

So I was thinking something was wrong with VS2015, and i didnt knew of ways to troubleshoot vs2015 in this area, eventually i found the cause trough event viewer.

Resolved by turning back to previous windows 10 build.

Goodbye cortana....